# After upload on my ftp, deviceorientation not working

Tags: javascript, ftp, orientation, device

I checked in my computer by opening just html and deviceorientation worked. On Chrome emulator, IT WORKED. But after upload on my ftp, it suddenly doesn't move.

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
      var alpha = event.alpha;
      var gamma = event.gamma;
      var beta = event.beta;
      console.log("working!!")
      handleOrientationEvent(alpha, gamma, beta);
    }, true);
  }

  var handleOrientationEvent = function( alpha, gamma, beta) {
    $("#message").css({
      'transform': 'rotateX(' + Math.floor(alpha) + 'deg) rotateY(' + Math.floor(gamma) + 'deg) rotateZ(' + Math.floor(beta) + 'deg)'
    });
    console.log("working!");
  }
```

Comment: What does "down't work" mean? Any errors? are you sure that `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` is true? What logs do you see?

Comment: If I open html file in my local laptop, deviceorientation worked. But after I upload same files on my homepage, it doesn't work at all(deviceorientation not working.)

Comment: Again: "Doens't work" is not a problem description. Can you verify that the listener gets added?

Comment: On my local(not uploaded on ftp), it says 'deviceorientation', which means it worked! But after uploading on my homepage via ftp, it says no global listeners. Sorry for making you misunderstanding.

Comment: Then `if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {` is false ...

Comment: I'm sorry for keep asking this so long. But I checked it is true. And only local, it is tilted when I move the emulator on chrome.

Comment: Then the listener does get added?

Comment: Yes, 'deviceorientation' is added on global listeners. But in my website, it doesn't tilt... Here's my link: http://www.jerremykim.com/orientation/

Comment: Works for me (Chrome on Android)

Comment: OMG REALLY?? Why only mine doesn't work.... :( Sorry and Thanks Jonas....